# Правописание кратких причастий с недо-

Tags: орфография

Слитно или раздельно пишутся краткие причастия : крепкий чай (не)допит,костюм (не)дошит, посуда (не)домыта?!!

Answer (score 7):

НЕ с краткими причастиями пишется раздельно.

В глаголах возможна приставка НЕДО, которая обозначает, что действие выполнено ниже нормы: в войну дети недоедали (ели меньше нормы) - в детском саду дети не доедают кашу (действие не доведено до конца). Что-то на ум не приходят причастия с приставкой НЕДО. В ваших примерах приставки НЕДО  тоже нет. НЕ пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 4):

Не домыта -т.е. процесс мытья посуды остался на половину.Недомыта  -вымата плохо.

Answer (score 0):

***Частица "не" пишется слитно:***

*- С полными причастиями без зависимых
   слов. Примеры: недописанное
   сочинение, несъеденный пирожок.*
 - *С причастиями и наречиями,
   оканчивающимися на "-о", если к ним
   относятся слова: совсем, совершенно,
   очень, весьма, крайне, чрезвычайно и
   т.д. Примеры: совсем недолго, очень
   нескоро, крайне недолго.*
 - *С отглагольными прилагательными на
   "-мый". Примеры: невесомый,
   неведомый.*

***Частица "не" пишется раздельно:***

- *С полными причастиями, если есть
     зависимые слова или
     противопоставление. Примеры: "это не
     разбитая, а лишь треснутая ваза",
     "это не доеденный мной пирожок".*
- *С краткими прилагательными, которые
     не употребляются в полной форме.
     Примеры: не рад, не готов.*

*С отглагольными прилагательными, оканчивающимися на "-мый", если есть зависимые слова или отрицательные местоимения.
Примеры: никаким средствами не досягаемая цель.*

Comment: А где же ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Действительно, есть обо всем, только не о кратких причастиях.